# Issue related to declaring Variable in Famo.Us

Tags: javascript, jquery, famo.us

I have Small application in Famo.us Framewok.

I want to declare array variable that can be use in calling js.

I have 2 .js file:  (1) PageView.js (2) GetContent.js

```
 (1) PageView.js
     function AddContent() {
     View.apply(this, arguments);
     var getContent = new GetContent();
     getContent.AddPages();

(2)GetContent.js

 function GetContent() {
       View.apply(this, arguments);
     }
    GetContent.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
    GetContent.prototype.constructor = GetContent;

    GetContent.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {};

    GetContent.prototype.AddPages = function () {

        GetData();
    }
```

I want to declare array variable in `GetContent.js` file that can be accessible in `PageView.js` using the object of `GetContent` defiened in `PageView.js` in above code.
so that i can use like `getContent.variablename[1]`

how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetContent` class would need to have an array assigned to it's instance like so:

```
this.variablename[1, 2, 3];
```

Adding `this` allows your array to be attached to the class's specific instance. Otherwise, your array will only exist for the lifetime of the function scope you create it in.

You may also find that you can't access the getContent object after it's been created in your PageView for the same reason. Instead try `this.getContent = new GetContent();`

Lastly, try to avoid directly accessing other class's variables directly. Instead, use getter/setter methods which allow the class to share and modify their data securely.

Comment: how to define Getter and Setter ? what is syntex ??